# PDF en ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf

tengo el siguiente inconveniente , tengo un controller en el que hago un query en el que obtengo 10 valores distintos cada vez que realizo el query; pero tambien a la vez genero un pdf con wicked_pdf  con los valores con los valores de la misma consulta.

El problema que tengo es que cuando renderizo los datos  en mi vista , quiero generar un pdf con los mismo datos , pero al generar el pdf  los datos varian totalmente , es decir la consulta se ejecuta  otra vez, Como podria evitar esto ?,

Controller

```
def index
  @test = Test.find_by(name: params[:test])
  @questions = TestQuestion.joins(:test).where(test_id:@test.id).order('RANDOM()').limit(10)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf { render template: 'simulators/pdf', pdf: 'pdf'}
  end
end
```

Agradesco por adelantado , cualquier comentario que me pueda dar otro enfoque para poder solucionar este problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo saber cual es el problema. El detalle está en `.order('RANDOM()')` cada vez que haces una llamada al método del controlador se genera un nuevo arreglo por lo tanto obtienes resultados diferentes. Lo que podrías hacer cambiar el `RANDOM()` por algo más específico.

U otra opción desde el método index obtuvieras los ID's de las  @question se lo pasara a una nueva ruta.

```
    def index
      @test = Test.find_by(name: params[:test])
      @questions = TestQuestion.joins(:test).where(test_id:@test.id).order('RANDOM()').limit(10)
      # Esta linea te regresara un arreglo con los puros IDS de la preguntas
      @question_ids = @questions.map{|question| question.id} 
    end
```

Crear un nuevo método en tu controlador que reciba esos IDs

```
  def to_pdf
    question_ids = params[:question_ids].to_a
    @questions = Question.where(id:@question_ids)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.pdf { render template: 'simulators/pdf', pdf: 'pdf'}
    end
  end
```

Agregar la ruta

```
    get 'tests/to_pdf' => 'test#to_pdf', as:'test_to_pdf'
```

Y finalmente agregar un botón a tu vista que mande a esa ruta

```
<%= link_to 'Descargar PDF', test_to_pdf_path(@question_ids) %>
```

En mi opinión esto te podría funcionar. Pero sin dudo lo mas fácil sería, como te dije al principio, hacer el `RANDOM()` algo mas específico.

Comment: Hola Cesar , muchas gracias esto me acaba de salvar el dia, pero tengo curiosidad  , de que manera podrias hacer el ´RANDOM()' mas especifico como lo harias tu . Disculpame si es una pregunta tonta pero aun soy un noob en rails.

Comment: Un placer ayudarte. En cuanto al random, como su nombre lo dice que va a tomar 10 registro de forma aleatoria. En cambios si los ordenas ya sea por fecha de creación `order('created_at ASC')` o por titulo o algún atributo que elijas, pues tu consulta sera mas concisa.

Comment: Yo ya tengo mas o menos experiencia desarrollando el rails, si necesitas ayuda con me puedes enviar un mensaje por twitter https://twitter.com/CeosWeb1 con gusto te ayudo

Comment: Gracias  Cesar , lo tendre muy en cuenta.